# Keeping your emojis up to date in Ubuntu 20.04 - a better way? Some PPA?

Tags: 20.04, updates, fonts, ppa, emoji

I was about to send a message through WhatsApp Web in Firefox, and I wanted to illustrate it with a [Saluting Face emoji](https://emojipedia.org/saluting-face/) - . To my disappointment, this showed as a hex box. It's too recent. I looked around and ended up installing [a newer version of `fonts-noto-color-emoji`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/jammy/amd64/fonts-noto-color-emoji/2.034-1). It works wonderfully, the newer emojis show OK.

My question is, is there a PPA for newer versions of this package so I wouldn't have to `dpkg -i` it manually every now and then?

Answer (score 1):

This package contains [only three files](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/all/fonts-noto-color-emoji/filelist) where main file is *NotoColorEmoji.ttf*, simply install the recent version by

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fonts-noto-color-emoji/fonts-noto-color-emoji_2.034-1_all.deb
sudo apt-get install ./fonts-noto-color-emoji_2.034-1_all.deb
```

and enjoy.

If you do not like above method, then create a script to fetch fonts from https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-emoji/tree/main/fonts and install them to user's fonts directory.

Comment: would that be used automatically from all other applications?
I usually select emojis with GNOME Characters, but doesn't seem to get updated after running the installation commands above.